# Regular expression to verify that string contains { }

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression to verify that a string contains { } but not { or }.Can someone shine some light on this please?

Thanks for all the help , here are some examples.

e.g.

valid : {abc}, as09{02}dd, {sdjafkl}sdjk, sfdsjakl,00{00}00, aaaaa{d}

invalid: {sdsf , sdfadf},sdf{Sdfs ,333}333

*********Update*******************

^[a-zA-Z0-9_-. ]*(?:{[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+})?[a-zA-Z0-9_-. ]*$ is what I need,thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Could you clarify?  Is it exactly "{}" (with no intervening characters) that you want?  Or do you just mean the string contains both { and } but not only one of them?  What about multiple { and }?  The requirements are ambiguous.

Comment: Provide some specimen inputs - your question as it stands doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please be more precise. Can there be any characters between {}? Examples would help.

Comment: The funny thing is that the best way to describe exactly what is and isn't allowed is a regex itself :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/.*\{.*\}.*/
```

This would ensure that the string contains an opening curly bracket somewhere before a closing curly bracket, occurring anywhere in the string.  However, it wouldn't be able to ensure that there's only one opening and closing curly bracket -- to do that, the `.*` patterns would have to be changed to something more restrictive.

If you want to experiment and test these regexes out, [here's a good site](http://www.quanetic.com/Regex).

Comment: This will match "{abc}{" which is probably not what he wants.

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\. ]*(?:\{[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\})?[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\. ]*$ is what I need,thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

What flavor of regex? In JavaScript, for instance, this'll do it:

```
var re = /\{.*\}/;

alert("A: " + re.test("This {is} a match"));
alert("B: " + re.test("This {is not a match"));
alert("C: " + re.test("This } is not a match"));
```

Alerts `A: true`, `B: false`, and `C: false`.

Most other flavors will be similar.

Comment: `alert("D: " + re.test("This {should} not be } a match"));`

Comment: @Svante: At the time I answered, the question didn't indicate that (no examples, virtually no detail at all). Heck, I'm still not sure it does. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For this problem regex-based solution is way too heavy.
If you have the opportunity of NOT using regexes - don't, simpler statement(s) can handle it just fine.

---

Even much general problem - checking, if the use of (potentially nested) parentheses is correct - is solvable using simple one-pass loop.

I.e. this is correct

```
{}{{{}{}}}
```

while this isn't

```
{{}
```

Solution in python (easy to translate to other language):

```
def check(s):
    counter = 0
    for character in s:
        if character == "{":
            counter += 1
        elif character == "}":
            counter -= 1

        if counter < 0:
            # not valid
            return False

    if counter == 0:
        # valid
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: The lexer will still complain.

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly one opening brace and exactly one closing brace in the string, and the closing brace follows the opening brace:

```
^[^\{\}]\{[^\{\}]\}[^\{\}]$
```

There any number of braces in the string, but they are not nested (there is never another opening brace before the previous one has been closed), and they are always balanced:

```
^[^\{\}](\{[^\{\}]\})*[^\{\}]$
```

Nesting cannot be generally solved by regular expressions.

Comment: However, note that most languages don't use strictly "regular" expressions. As an example, the Perl regex `/(\{(?:[^\{\}]++|(?1))*\})/` will match balanced curly braces.