# Regular Expression to verify condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a new to JavaScript. I have tried to use regular expression in `if`condition.
Here is my code:

```
var location1 = 3;
var location2 = 4;
var location3 = 5;

var guess;
var hits = 0;
var guesses = 0;
var string = "";
var reg = /[0-6]/i;

var isSunk = false;

while (isSunk == false) {
guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number 0-6): ");
if (guess != reg || guess ==string) {
    alert("Please enter a valid cell number!");
} else {
    guesses = guesses + 1;

if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {

        hits = hits + 1;
        alert("HIT!");

        if (hits == 3) {
            isSunk = true;
            alert("You sank my battleship!");
        }
    } else {
        alert("MISS!");
    }
}
}
var stats = "You took " + guesses + " guesses to sink the battleship, " +    "which means your shooting accuracy was " + (3 / guesses);
alert(stats);`
```

My problem is in this `if (guess != reg || guess ==string)` condition. It didn't work as I expected. I would like that function `prompt` allows only 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 numbers without any words and spaces. But in fact If I enter one of needed number (1 for example) it won't allow to execute further actions. I read a lot through **stackoverflow** about regular expression in Javascript ([Convert the Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043653/convert-the-regular-expression-to-used-in-javascript), [Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856744/regular-expression-to-verify-that-string-contains), [Basic regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347333/basic-regular-expression-in-javascript)) and more but I could not find the answer to my problem.
So the question is:

> How to set proper regular expression in `if` condition in JavaScript if it has already declared as variable?

Comment: You need to test your regular expression against its value, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Comment: `guess != reg` here you compare a user string with a regex object; this is not correct, you need to `reg.test(guess)`  You also need to anchor the regex  `/^[0-6]$/` to  make it match 1 digit

Comment: Murtaza, actually, I have already done this here http://www.regexr.com and everything was alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test whether a string matches a regular expression you can't just compare them using the standard comparison operators. Something that should work is

```
if (reg.test(guess)) {
    ....
}
```

Also the regular expression `[0-6]i` also matches the string `"hello1`, since there is a one in it. What you want is probably something like `^[0-6]$`. The test for the empty string is also unnecessary, by the way, since `""` does not match that expression.

To explain: The `^` and the `$` match the beginning and the end of the string, respectively. Framing a regular expression with these symbols essentially says that the whole string, not only a substring, has to match the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression are not the right tool here.

```
 guess = prompt("Ready, aim, fire! (enter a number 0-6): ");
 guess = +guess;   // Convert *guess* to number, sets to NaN if not numeric
 if (guess >= 0 && guess <= 6) {  // check if number is in range (NaN will fail)
     ....
```